# @LastModifiedBy and @LastModifiedDate not working for embedded object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to use **`@LastModifiedDate`** and **`@LastModifiedBy`** annotations to auditing my records in MongoDB.

Here my Model are

```
    @Document(collection = "A")
    class A{
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedUser;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;
    private List<B> listB;
    }

    class B{
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedUser;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;
    }

Service1.class
public class Service1 {
 public void saveA(A a) {
      repository.save(a)
      }
 }
```

It's working fine for **`class A`** but it's not working with embedded **`class B`**.

Any help will be appreciate.

using `2.1.10- Spring Data Mongo and for Springboot 2.1.8.Release`

Comment: It's `2.1.10- Spring Data Mongo and for Springboot 2.1.8.Release`

Comment: what's the difference when interacting with `A` and `B`? can you provide minimal reproducible code?

Comment: While adding entry into Mongo DB i am able to get value for `lastModifiedUser` and `lastModifiedDate` for A but inside of that List for B i am not getting both values.

Comment: it seems like this is a known issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1440, maybe this post will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324188/spring-data-mongodb-auditing-doesnt-work-for-embedded-documents

Comment: @shahaf, i had already go through that post, not able to get any resolution.

Comment: post a minimal reproducible code, I'll try to help

Comment: @shahaf, i had added my service class code also, just try to save document A and which contains field as `List<B>` and in B i am unable to get `@LastModifiedBy` values

Comment: where is your configuration which activates `lastModified`

Comment: please read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't much on your post to get the behaviour of the final solution you are aiming for... so I'll try my best :)

as the day of this post was written, spring have a known issue with audit of embed document as stated [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1440), so you'll have to override the `audit` interface with your own logic for setting and changing the `lastModifiedUser` and `lastModifiedDate` fields, this is possible but not so easy and may introduce un-desired behaviour to the functionality of `spring-data` in your project

or

you can force all changes of `B` by a custom method, so every modification of `List<B>` will trigger a "change check" (this is not involved any `spring-data` capabilities)

another approach will be (my suggestion)

use `B` as a separate document, and store in `A` the list of b's refs using `@DBRef`